# RxJava2 not receiving doOnNext after toList

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I was working on project in which I wanted to iterate on an List and combine them back before returning the results. Basically I'm trying to convert an `PostResponse` object to `Post`.

Some Relevant Codes.

Post.java

```
public class Post {
    @NonNull private User user;
    @NonNull private String title;
    @NonNull private String body;
    @NonNull private Integer id;
}
```

PostResponse.java

```
public final class PostResponse{
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
}
```

Get Posts

```
 @Override public Observable<List<Post>> posts() {
        return postDataStore.getAllPosts()
                .flatMap(postResponses -> Observable.fromIterable(postResponses)
                        .flatMap(postResponse -> postDataMapper.transform(postResponse))
                        // Receiving output here
                        .doOnNext(post -> Log.i(TAG, "posts: " + post))
                        .toList()
                        .toObservable()
                        // Not Receiving output here
                        .doOnNext(posts -> Log.i(TAG, "posts: " + posts)));
    }
```

Transform function called above.

```
public Observable<Post> transform(final PostResponse postResponse) {
        return Observable.create(emitter -> {
            final Post post = new Post(postResponse.getId());
            post.setTitle(postResponse.getTitle());
            post.setBody(postResponse.getBody());
            userRepository.user(postResponse.getUserId()).doOnNext(user -> {
                post.setUser(user);
                emitter.onNext(post);
            }).subscribe();
        });
    }
```

But I'm not receiving any data on `doOnNext` that is subscribed to `posts()`. Not sure what is wrong.

My apologies if I'm making a really silly mistake.

Comment: Replace `postDataStore.getAllPosts()` with some source of data which 100% has a data, e.g. Observable from list, and check. If you get something in `onNext` it means that your `postDataStore` doesn't return anything

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question so it should be much clearer. `getAllPosts` was emitting fine.

Comment: The `toList()` operator requires that the observable completes. Does your observable complete?

Comment: @BobDalgleish not sure how we complete an observable .

Comment: An observable is completed when `onComplete()` is called or `onError()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add:

`emitter.onComplete();`

right after your `emitter.onNext(post);`

BUT, I would recommend to rethink the design and the logic. In particular your transformation doesn't need to create a new `Observable`. I would redesign your `tranform` method in something like this:

```
Observable<Post> transform(PostResponse postResponse) {
    return userRepository.user(postResponse.getUserId())
        .map(user -> parseResponse(parseResponse, user));
}


Post parseResponse(PostResponse response, User user) {
    final Post post = new Post(postResponse.getId());
    post.setTitle(postResponse.getTitle());
    post.setBody(postResponse.getBody());   
    post.setUser(user);

    return post;
}
```

In this way you avoid to create a new `Observable`, you avoid inner subscriptions, and you have a single control point for the result, that is in the subscription of the final resulting `Observable`.